# Form Validation - proper method for client and server side using PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

--edit--
(Trying to rephrase my question to be less confusing..)

My understanding is that you should validate forms both client and server side in case Javascript is not working.

How do advanced developers accomplish this in a seamless interface (if one had to describe in a general manner)?

Currently I have Javascript validating my input fields on the fly with 'onkeyup ()', highlighting invalid fields.

If I run the same validations with PHP after the user submits, then I have to redirect to the form if there were any errors, refreshing the page.

I thought this method was lacking sophistication.

What would be the best method?

Thanks in advance.

--- original question below ---

So I created a form with client side javascript to validate the input as the user types. It highlights the boxes w red borders if the data is invalid (using javascript to alter the css). I would like to re-validate the same data with php server side in case of any problems with javascript client side.

I am trying to figure out what is the proper (or best) way to accomplish this.

Currently the form action is setup to go to "register_post.php" after user hits submit.

--

So do I just validate the form data in PHP in "register_post.php", and redirect back to the form page if something is invalid, or is there a more sophisticated way to do this?

One annoying result of this is the page refreshing when the page is redirected.

Is there a more sophisticated way to do this?

--

Another related question is - should I prep my code for javascript not working at all? ..since currently, I use javascript to highlight the fields if the data is invalid. The user will have no indication of which fields are invalid without js.

please bear with me as I am a beginner.

Comment: show us the code of the form else we can't help you

Comment: I think the code is irrelevant for this particular general question. I have a form in html with js validating and highlighting invalid fields with a red border. The javascript functions are triggered with onkeyup. e.g. onkeyup="validateEmail()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to valid the post data with PHP and without refresh the page, I don't know if I get your point right. If you want to valid the data with PHP and without refreshing page, you could use AJAX. You can use javascript to post data to a PHP script and deal PHP return data.

An example of jquery ajax method :

```
<script>
var validDataArr = '';  //data need to be valided
$.ajax({
            type:"post",url:"http://"+top.location.hostname+"/valid.php",
            data:validDataArr,
            success:function(context){alert(context);}

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I think you got the point. Sorry for the confusion. Is there any way to run a PHP script to validate the data without leaving the page upon the user hitting submit? Is there a way without using AJAX?

Comment: I'm afraid you must use AJAX in that case, but a javascript framework as JQuery provides a easy way to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

While submitting the form , call a javascript function to validate the fields and throw an error if it not suits.

you can call a js function as below

```
input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button2" value="Submit" onClick="javascript:verify()"/>
```

Try this , this will help you to understand the basic validation

http://jsfiddle.net/NWWL4/15/

Comment: Yes, I already have JS validating the inputs and highlighting invalid fields. My understanding is that you should also validate with PHP server-side in case JS is not working. My question is how do advanced developers implement both client & server side validations in a clean interface that does not refresh the page upon submit?

Comment: for that they are using the ajax request to transfer the data and validate it and returns an error without refreshing the page. if you need the you too use the ajax request.

Comment: Is AJAX the only way to accomplish this? If I use AJAX/PHP to validate the data, then I don't need to with JS?